# Java EE - How HttpServlet works/creates?

Tags: jakarta-ee

When the HttpServlet creates:

1. every time after it is called by client (by form submit,..)?
2. after its project's WAR (for example) is deployed on (tomcat) server?
3. after first client's call?
4. or on other time..?

I have same question for init method - when is it called?

---

I want to read data from Oracle (SQL) DataBase and save it in variables, cause don't want to read/get data from database every time client calls doPost method (if I write connection, statement and resultset objects in doPost method...). So, where can I save data, which never changes during Servlet working; this data would be used by every client on form calls.
One told me that it's not right to use class's variables, cause some of them are not thread-safe. So, **what is best way to use for data save and use this data for multiple clients' calls?**

*Sorry for my bad English...*

Comment: google the web application servlet lifecycle...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows a lack of minimal research.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow your question, but to connect your SQL database you can use MySQL connector, and to store the values, store them in java only.. Use resultset.getString() and resultset.getInt() functions to get values from the database and store it in variables :) hope this helps..

Also for information about servlets read the tab info on stack overflow